# How can I export/import Array.prototype.customFunction in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, prototype, global

I have a file `extensions/array.ts` with the following code:

```
Array.prototype.randomPick = function() {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};
```

And also a `extensions/string.ts`:

```
String.prototype.capitalizeFirstLetter = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};
```

These are consumed from `helpers/name-helper.ts`:

```
import '../extensions/string';
import '../extensions/array';

declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        randomPick(): T;
    }
    interface String {
        capitalizeFirstLetter(): string;
    }
}

export default class NameHelper {
    static generate() {
        const adjetives = ['creepy', 'dark', 'desolate', 'bloody', 'green', 'dangerous', 'terrible', 'cold', 'windy', 'cozy'];
        const places = ['meadows', 'hills', 'desert', 'dungeons', 'forest', 'cavern', 'underworld', 'town', 'city', 'castle', 'tower', 'house'];

        return adjetives.randomPick().capitalizeFirstLetter() + ' ' + places.randomPick().capitalizeFirstLetter();
    }
};
```

I had to include the `declare global` with the `interface Array<T>` in `name-helper` so Typescript wouldn't complain about `Array.randomPick()` not existing, but this would mean I'd end up copying and pasting the interface declaration for Array everywhere I use it...

I have the same problem with `window` somewhere else in the code, and also with `interface CanvasRenderingContext2D`, so I can see this becoming an issue in the future.

Is there any way to move the `interface Array<T>` declaration to `array.ts`?

I'm using Typescript 2.0.3

Comment: Actually, you only have to extend the Array interface in a single place, and extend the prototype in a single place as well. No imports should be needed, typescript should take care of all that on it's own.

Comment: Hey that works, thanks @toskv! Indeed in this case it seems to be a duplicate of that question.

I've got this other case that I can't get to work though, dunno if it deserves a new question: it's exactly the same, but for CanvasRenderingContext2D and Window interfaces. I can't seem to make it work with those.

Comment: I did a test with window and CanvasRenderingContext2D and they work just fine. :)

Comment: I feel I tried everything and I still get the compilation error – I'm gonna accept this as a duplicate and open a new question for this case.